# Remove some keys when converting from custom type into Map using Jackson's convertValue

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a rather simple Java object that I would like to convert it into a `Map<String, Object>` using Jackson's `convertValue(fromValue, toValueTypeRef)` — this is rather trivial.

At the same time, there are some fields/members (e.g.: `createdOn` and `modifiedOn`) I would like to remove from the resultant `Map`, but I can't remove them in all (de)serialization routines. I was wondering if there is a way to tell Jackson to do that, rather than removing them "by hand". I've usually seen `@JsonView` used for such purposes, but I think it doesn't work with `convertValue` — or I'm still unable to configure it correctly.

This is how I'm doing the conversion:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
public final class CustomTypeMapper {
  private static final TypeReference<Map<String, Object>> MAP_TYPE_REFERENCE = new TypeReference<>() { };

  private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper(); // ...with some customizations

  public Map<String, Object> convertFrom(final CustomType input) {
    // OBJECT_MAPPER.writerWithView(Views.Public.class);
    return OBJECT_MAPPER.convertValue(input, MAP_TYPE_REFERENCE);
  }
}
```

`CustomType` looks roughly like this:

```java
@Getter
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public final class CustomType {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private String id;

  @JsonProperty("user")
  private User user;

  ...

  @Builder.Default
  @JsonProperty("created_on") // TODO: Exclude this field/member some times
  @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
  private final Instant createdOn = Instant.now();

  @Builder.Default
  @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
  @JsonProperty("modified_on") // TODO: Exclude this field/member some times
  private Instant modifiedOn = Instant.now();
}
```

Comment: How about creating a setter and discarding the input?

Comment: You mean something like nullifying the relevant field(s) before calling `convertValue`? If that's so, wouldn't it be a very similar approach than removing some elements from the `Map`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you were converting from a Map to a POJO.

Comment: Have you looked at `@JsonFilter`?

Comment: *or I'm still unable to configure it correctly* - if you're not sure you're using it right, try it with ordinary serialization. If that works, you can always go with the (admittedly less efficient) serialize-then-deserialize approach.

Comment: Another thing you can do is have a special subtype that you use just for this serialization that excludes fields (and you can use composition with `lombok.experimental.Delegate` since your class is `final`). That class will override the getters of these two fields and annotate them with `@JsonIgnore`.  Although that's an extra class, it's simple.